# I can't import the database throgh PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to import database through PHPMyAdmin. My database file is abc.sql and it's size is 50.9 MB. I am trying this on local and it's saying:

> You probably tried to upload a file that is too large. Please refer to documentation for ways to workaround this limit.

Please Help with this.

Comment: Use compressed dumps

Comment: Increase _`max_upload_size`_ in `php.ini` that your server currently use, also increase the _`max_execution_time`_

Answer (score 2):

You can update the maximum upload size from php.ini file.

In the php.ini you need to update the 3 values as per your requirement

- upload_max_filesize
- post_max_size
- memory_limit

Then restart your apache server. You will able to import the database.

Comment: Where i can find php.ini file??

Comment: Which server you are using? Wamp, Xampp or Mamp?

Comment: I am using the Xampp Server

Comment: You can find php.ini file in the C:\xampp\php\php.ini or in the etc Folder.

Answer (score 1):

Just use mysql CLI -

1) Command Prompt 
2) `mysql -uusername -p` (enter password when prompted) 
3) `use database_name` 
4) `source C:\path\to\file.sql`

Comment: What does this mean "#1046 - No database selected" ??

Comment: @AmiPadia my bad forgot the use statement, it's as the error message suggests, you haven't selected a database - see edit

Comment: I am importing database to phpmyadmin.

Comment: Error
SQL query:


--
-- Table structure for table `ib_adminpanelmenus`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ib_adminpanelmenus`
MySQL said: 

#1046 - No database selected

Comment: @AmiPadia phpMyAdmin isn't a database

Comment: @AmiPadia what database are you importing to? replace database_name with that one

Comment: In local system i don't have any table like "ib_adminpanelmenus" than why it still showing this??